# system verilog interface for multiple clocks

Tags: interface, verification, system-verilog, vlsi

My DUT is a memory controller. I have to write a system verilog interface for the DUT.
Memory Controller DUT supports 32 AXI Masters.
When I am writing an AXI interface, it will consist of ACLK which is generated and passed on through the top(verification). When I am connecting this interface to the DUT, will there be 32(AXI ACLK) + 1(clk on which DUT is working) , inall 33 clks to the DUT..
I am quite confused in these.
logically there should be only one clk in the DUT..

Thanks in advance for the answers

Answer (score 0):

*Shared* interface signals should be declared as input ports to your interface. That way you can tie them all together to make one logical signal.

```
interface myintf(input wire sig_shared);

  wire sig_internal;

endinterface

module top;

  wire s1,s2;

  myintf i1(s1);
  myintf i2(s1);

  myintf i[31:0](s2);

endmodule
```

Now signals `i1.sig_internal` and `i2.sig_internal` will be independent, but `i1.sig_shared` and `i2.sig_shared` are logically equivalent. Same thing for `i[0].sig_shared` thru `i[31].sig_shared`.